# exerdices on proving inequality between "=" and little o

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

i am trying to prove that if
$x^9=o(M(x)^{\delta}))$,  $\forall $ $ \delta >0$

then $ x^9=M(x)^{o(1)} $
where $M(x)=e^{\pi (x) \log \log x}$

$\pi (x)$ is the prime counting fonction

my attempt

using $\epsilon $ definition we get

$x^9<\epsilon M(x)^{\delta}$ ,$\forall $ $ \delta >0$

taking $\epsilon=1 $   we get

$x^9< M(x)^{o(1)}$

but i could not prove the other inequality,

is there a better way to prove it?